# Sending e-mail with addresses in worksheet column

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a sheet called "Test" where column A is a list of e-mail addresses.
I want to send an e-mail to all addresses.

```vb
Sub EmailSend()
    
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objMail As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
    
    For i = 1 To 10
        With objMail
           .to = Sheets("Test").Range("A" & i).Value
           .Subject = "hi"
           .body = _ 
              "Hi " & Sheets("Test").Range("B" & i) & Sheets("links").Range("G" & 1)
           .send
        End With
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

The macro sends an e-mail to the address in A1 and then an error

> element was moved or deleted.

appears in the line

```
.to = Sheets("Test").Range("A" & i).Value
```

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: @StavrosJon that the element was moved.

Comment: This works for me as well... change `.send` to `.display` and see what the email you are sending actually contains.

Comment: @rohrl77 Did it and it contains all the thinks I want, exactly as I want them to be. Also, for the first adress it does work and the e-mail is send correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess that the second line you are trying to send might have an error. Therefore, use the code below and check what it shows in the Immediate window.

UPDATE:
I've added the `CreateItem` line within the `For` loop and am resetting it for each mail. Possible it is the mail item that the error message is complaining about.

```
Sub EmailSend()

Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objMail As Object
Dim i As Integer

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For i = 1 To 10
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

With objMail
    Debug.Print Sheets("Test").Range("A" & i).Value
   .to = Sheets("Test").Range("A" & i).Value
   .Subject = "hi"
   .body = _
      "Hi " & Sheets("Test").Range("B" & i) & Sheets("links").Range("G" & 1)
   .display
   '.send
End With
Set objMail = Nothing

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: It shows everything correctly but still, your code gives me same error message once I change it to `.send`

Comment: I updated my answer... try the new code. See explanation in update.